# Need specific filenames similar to input files upon conversion to .tif files

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff, netcdf

I am working on conversion of multiple .nc files (3 hourly data) to .tif files.

The issue that I am facing is the original file names are as follows: 3B42A.20050101.18.7A.SUB.nc;
3B42A.20050101.21.7A.SUB.nc; 3B42A.20050102.00.7A.SUB.nc; 3B42A.20050102.03.7A.SUB.nc; 3B42A.20050102.06.7A.SUB.nc.... and so on
And on conversion to .tif, it is giving me output files as 1.tif, 2.tif...... But I want original file names in the output, i.e. 20050101.18.tif; 20050101.21.tif; 20050102.00.tif; 20050102.03.tif; 20050102.06.tif;.....and so on for entire year.

Can anyone help me with this. I am working in R.

Naming convention of files is as follows: '3B42A' is the data product name. '2005' is the year 2005, '01' is month and '01' or '02' are dates. '18','21','00','03','06' = data at 6pm, 9pm, 12am, 3am and 6am respectively (i.e. 3 hourly data as mentioned above).

Commands I am using is as follows:

```
    > library ("raster")
    > library ("ncdf4")
    > rasterfiles   <- list.files("F://TestCoding//Test", "*.nc", full.names = TRUE)
    > d1 <-  stack(rasterfiles)
    > d2=unstack(d1)
    > outputnames <- paste(seq_along(d2), ".tif",sep="")
    > for(i in seq_along(d2)){writeRaster(d2[[i]], file=outputnames[i])}
```

Comment: Could you click 'edit' and share the code you are using? Please specify which packages you are loading as well.

Comment: I've given you an answer below, but note that this is not really a GIS question and may get closed!

Answer (score 1):

Use your original filenames as the output filenames, modified with substitution:

```
# Change extension:
outputnames <- gsub(pattern = ".nc",
                    replacement = ".tif",
                    x = rasterfiles)
# Get rid of the parts you don't want:
outputnames <- gsub(pattern = "(3B42A.|.7A.SUB)", 
                    replacement = "",
                    x = outputnames)
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is not able to change the names of my files, or do anything in fact. Nor it is giving me any error!! Could you figure out what could be the reason.

Comment: @Akb, this code should replace your `outputnames <- paste(seq_along(d2), ".tif",sep="")`, which only uses the list indices (1, 2, etc) instead of full filenames. – Simbamangu 5 hours ago